# calculating the Big O of using C++ std function instead of for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, std

If I'm implementing a for loop to shift elements to the right between two indices in an array it would take me O(n) to shift those elements, but instead what if I used library function like `std::rotate` that would be executed in one step, so does that means that it took constant time.

like this example

```
vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

int temp = arr[5];

for(int i = 5 ; i >= 3 ; i--){


    arr[i]=arr[i-1];

}

arr[2] = temp;
```

so   `arr`    would be     {1,2,6,3,4,5,7,8,9,10}

Instead I could do

```
 rotate(arr.begin()+2,arr.begin()+5,arr.begin()+6);
```

...and that would result into the same shifted array

But the first one takes about 3 steps and the other is just 1 step, is that true?

Comment: Information [found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: well it might be one line code but it still has to make n iteration to rotate it, exemple you can create a function with your code & call it (it's a one line code but  that doesnt make it a constate complexity functiion )

Comment: Note that, if you're defining "n" as the length of arr, both `for(int i = 5 ; i >= 3 ; i--){` and `rotate(arr.begin()+2,arr.begin()+5,arr.begin()+6);` are **O(1)**.

Comment: The "number of steps" as measured in lines of source code has no meaning at all.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yup thats for sure, I was only wondering if C++ compiler has pulled some of his **black magic** when called the `rotate` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::rotate` has linear complexity, so while it might be marginally faster or slower than your code, the two use approximately the same number of steps to do the job.

In this particular case, its likely that `std::rotate` actually uses more steps, because it's coded to handle rotation by an arbitrary number of places, which is slightly more work than always rotating exactly one place like your code does. On the other hand, it's also possible that rotating by one place is common enough that the standard library could check for that, and use similar code to yours for that specific case.

Comment: If `std::rotate`'s arguments are constant expressions it seems reasonable to assume the compiler will inline and probably unroll the loop (if it's beneficial).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: In this case, the problem is with the algorithm, not things like loop unrolling. The usual implementation of `std::rotate` uses 2N swaps, where N is the number of items being rotated.

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear that I was replying specifically to the second part. If it can be determined that the number of steps is a constant expression (such as in this case) the extra overhead of supporting N sized steps may go away. It sounds like you interpreted my comment as disputing that both solutions are `O(N)`. I'm not saying optimizations will change that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: No, I'm not disputing anything,just pointing out that it would take a bit of extra work beyond the usual unrolling and such. Instead you'd have to actually switch to an entirely different algorithm if the number of elements you're rotating by is constant and, probably, below some threshold. So in theory, you're right that it could be done--but I haven't seen an implementation that does it, and honestly don't expect to soon either.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does takes linear time.Actual time complexity is the difference between initial and final node .Check out
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate